# Stored procedures for inserting into Cassandra

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, cassandra, nosql

I am migrating my database from SQL to Cassandra.

Right now, my application logic is decoupled from insert logic as the application only calls the specific procedures in SQL which calls some data validations and makes corresponding insertions.

I want to do the same in Cassandra. However, I am unable to find anything similar for Cassandra. UDFs are not useful as they are mostly used in select query.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? What do you mean by "SQL" ?? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: This is mssql .